# Questions on installing packages

Tags: discussion

When a new version of a language is released, we get a few of questions about difficulties installing packages. My particular case is [R](http://cran.r-project.org/). Last week, version 2.15 was released, people upgraded and found that some packages no longer work. For example,

- [failure of installing RTextTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998619/failure-of-installing-rtexttools)
- [What's up R 2.15 and proto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960973/whats-up-r-2-15-and-proto)

  - The answer to this question suggests upgrading the package!

These questions tend to be very local and I would suggest should be asked to the package author not SO. Should these questions be closed?

Answer (score 2):

From the SO [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>   - a specific programming problem
>   - a software algorithm
>   - software tools commonly used by programmers
>   - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

I think those question are definitely covered by the faq points 3 and 4.

If they are to localized has to be decided on each question.

In my opinion there can't be a definitive answer to your question. Those should be handled like all other questions. If you have problems with a particular one, use your possibilities to comment, downvote, flag or vote to close.

Comment: I just find that most of the questions I get about this sort of thing are too localized to help any future reader.  In particular it's almost impossible to give them decent titles because "Can't install <X>" could have so many different possibilities for any given <X> (and often not unique just to <X> either).  With Python libraries for example they typically involve basic problems with misconfigured `PYTHONPATH` that are not specific to my software.